# How to Populate CheckedListBox with the data from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im a beginner at C#. I have a form where at the CellDoubleClickEvent, it populates the text boxes of its respective columns, and vice-versa.
something like this :-

```
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewRoles.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                //ID, row.Cell[0] is where IDs are stored
                txtRolesUID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                //Rolename row.Cell[1] is for Rolenames, etc
                txtRolesRoleName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                //Description
                txtRolesRoleDescription.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            }
```

The problem is I dont know how to do it for a checked box or a list of items, like a combo box or drop down.

i tried with this, but as i dont know the syntax or the logic for it, it failed

```
                //Rights
                chklbRolesRoleRights.Items.Add(row.Cells[3]);
```

Comment: `row.Cells[3]` is a Cell object you presumably just want the value in the cell. See in your own code where you called multiple times `.Value` to get the cells value. Please if you run into errors in the future also tell the actual errors when asking.

Comment: my bad, but as i didnt mention it, there were no errors popping up, and the code ran just fine. Also, what i want to do is not just import the value, but the text and elements in the list, eg. theres a list of things in the database ```row.Cells[3]``` and when i use value, it adds the name of the field, which is weird since it shouldnt be happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to add the value to your combobox in your code using `.Add(row.Cells[3])` you're actually just adding the cell object to the items list, which is invalid.

What you want to do is add the value of `row.Cells[3]`, this is done by using the `Value` property of the cell object. Like so:

```cs
chklbRolesRoleRights.Items.Add(row.Cells[3].Value);
```

Just like you did in the first code snippet you included in the question.

If you want to prevent other complications from arising you can also add `.ToString()` which forces it to add a string value to the combobox/items list: `.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString())`.

EDIT: noticed @Ralf also pointed this out in the comments

Comment: alright so i ill try the ```.ToString``` method, but simply by diong ```.value```, i am not able to do so, as it imports the name of the checked list box, and not its items. dunno why this keeps happening. Thanks though!

Comment: I thought `row` was a datagridtable, not checked list box?

Comment: it IS of datagridtable, but i want to import that table row contents to the checklistbox. but eh ive found a roundabout to it for my use, so its all good